# Calculating the superficial degree of divergence for arbitrary nPIR diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, dimensional-analysis

In Weinberg QFT Vol 1 Ch. 12, he only calculates the superficial degree of divergence $D$ for 1PIR diagrams.

The formula is given by
\begin{equation}
D=4-\sum_f E_f(s_f+1)-\sum_i N_i \Delta_i
\end{equation}
where $E_f$ is the number of external legs for the field type $f$ and $-2(s_f+1)$ is the exponent for the propagator of the field type $f$. Also, $N_i$ is the number of vertices for the interaction type $i$ and $\Delta_i$ is the mass dimension of the coupling constant for the interaction type $i$.

I very recently noticed that this formula only works for 1PIR diagram. Could anyone please tell me how to find a more general formula of $D$ for arbitrary nPIR diagrams?

For example, in $\phi^4$ theory, how do we calculate $D$ of the figure $8$ vacuum diagram having one vertex? I know that the coupling constant has dimension $0$ and $s_f=0$ for the $\phi^4$ theory.

Comment: What do you mean? The formula holds for any connected diagram in 4D. What is your counterexample? The figure 8 has $D=4$.

Comment: Weinberg says he only considers 1PIR in which we must add every independent 4-momenta(=independent loops).

Comment: That is written in p.500 of his QFT Vol 1.

Comment: Weinberg is presumably only interested in 1-particle irreducible (1PIR) diagrams. Also note that an nPIR diagram is automatically 1PIR.

Comment: Oh...then how about just connected diagrams, which are 0PIR?

Comment: See my first comment.